# Squid Transparent + HTTPS

Tags: windows, ssl, https, squid, transparentproxy

I enable Squid transparent in windows using this method ([youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_rvIeUuSW8)). But after enabled, pages with HTTPS is showing error.

In Chrome this message is: SSL Connection Error (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

In Firefox: Security Connection Fail (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

IE: Check if TLS and SSL Protocols has enabled.

Is possible disable the SSL / HTTPS in squid?

Or solve this problem in another way.

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/Windows

> Squid features not operational:
>
> ```
> DISKD: still needs to be ported
> Transparent Proxy: missing Windows non commercial interception driver
> SMP support: Windows equivalent of UDS sockets has not been implemented
> ```

So it might not be possible to use squid as transparent proxy on window.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I didn't watch the video clip - but simply tell your browser to not use the proxy for HTTPS or port 443.

Alternately, if you're using the transparent firewall method, you can either tell the firewall to skip port 443, or to ONLY redirect port 80 through the proxy eg.

> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

the above will just accept HTTPS-port traffic and ignore all the other firewall rules for it

or

> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 3128

which will only redirect port 80 to your transparent squid.

PS It's a really bad idea to try and proxy SSL - it completely defeats the purpose of SSL.

Comment: I'm using Windows, so no have iptables.
I use a workaround and disable transparency on proxy and use Group Policy Management with GPO and set proxy config in users browsers.
Really i don't found how use SQUID transparency on windows with HTTPS.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh dang! I've forgotten that Windows existed. Thanks for bursting my bubble :-(